# Accessing request context in template without view - django

Tags: django, django-1.4

I have the following view that displays the user profile:

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    return render_to_response('registration/profile.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I access the user information through the `request.user` variable in the template.

I was thinking that it might be easier to just have a `direct_to_template` url, but then the request context won't be there.

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't the request context be there? All generic views use RequestContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is using [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview):

```
url(r'^...$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/profile.html'), name='...'),
```

**However**, according to the source code of direct_to_template:

```
def direct_to_template(request, template, extra_context=None, mimetype=None, **kwargs):
    """ 
    Render a given template with any extra URL parameters in the context as
    ``{{ params }}``.
    """
    if extra_context is None: extra_context = {}
    dictionary = {'params': kwargs}
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        if callable(value):
            dictionary[key] = value()
        else:
            dictionary[key] = value
    c = RequestContext(request, dictionary)
    t = loader.get_template(template)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type=mimetype)
```

direct_to_template uses RequestContext.